# Transform app.config file at Asp.Net Core solution publish?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core WebApi project with .NET Framework 4.6.1. And I also have an app.config file that contains endpoints for some WCF services. I have a corresponding app.config for each environment like Dev and Qa and so on. But when I publish the solution it doesn't transform the app.config based on the environment. Do you have any ideas on how I could do that?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SlowCheetah

Comment: How do you load your app.config for each environment? and what do you mean by "transform"

Comment: I right-clicked the app.config file and chose 'Add config transformations'. It generated a config file for each environment and I can even see the changes when I right click one of them and choose Preview cpnfig transform or something like that. But when I make the publish, it doesn't transform and copy the corresponding app.config file based on environment

Comment: @Alina which version of visual studio you are using 2015 / 2017? and asp.net core template - `project.json` based or `.csproj` based?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and project.json. I tried upgrading to .csproj, but I keep receiving some certificate issue at publish.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with is to add a post build command that copies the transformed web configs over the top of the MyProject.exe.config. In order for this to work you will need to copy the assembly redirect from your app.config(output) to your web.config. Then you only need one config file. This is not a great solution and I am going to implement a different way to reference the wcf connections using the appSettings.json and creating the clients in the C# code but, this will work for now. In our continuous integration build, I have a powershell command that does the same after build. One other caveat: I am deploying to IIS and need the web.config authentication settings (for windows auth) so I had to make sure the web.config and MyProject.exe.config both got deployed. This ended up being the same file, IIS using the peices it needs and the WCF client builder using the parts it needs. again we are not going to be using this for long and I would suggest building the WCF client programatically.

Update: I use the appsettings.json to include my environment based settings and added a way to connect to wcf using the system.servicemodel classes in .netStandard. it works great!